# How do you model something that looks wrinkled or crumpled?

Tags: bezier-curves, cloth-simulation

i wanted to model something like this in blender..
any ideas?

I have no idea how to manually add wrinkles to a mesh.

[image: Example:]

Comment: Rather than modelling, a cloth simulation would be better suited for that. This way the cloth will naturally fold and hang without the stretching tha would be very difficult to avoid with manual modelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Create the text

- Create a black and white image of your text in a software of your choice (Gimp, Krita, ...)
- Make sure your render engine is set to cycles, then use the add-on "Import images as planes" to bring the image of your text into blender. If you don't see this option in your import dialogue, activate the add-on in the [user preferences add-on panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html?). (It ships with blender, but it is initially deactivated)
- Change the shader the add-on created on import to the setup shown in my screenshot. This will blend a diffuse white shader with a transparent shader based on your text
- Subdivide your image a couple of times, you will need the extra geometry for the cloth simulation. Simulations work best with square faces, first use [loop cuts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop.html#loop-cut) <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to shorten the long side of the text, then use subdivide <kbd>w</kbd> to create more geometry

[image]

## Simulate the wrinkles

- in object mode, translate your image object a little on the z-axis, to make some room for the collision objects
- create a ground plane and several cubes where your wrinkles should be
- in the physics tab of your ground plane and the cubes, choose "Collision"
- in the physics tab of your image, choose "Cloth"
- run the simulation <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, play around with the cloth settings and the position and scaling of the collision objects to find the wrinkles you like

[image]

## Render your result

- add a camera and a sun-lamp to your scene, position them to your liking
- move the collision objects to another layer, so they won't appear in the final render, but remain in the scene in case you want to resimulate
- make sure your image plane is set to [shade smooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#smooth)
- to recreate the effect of your reference image, I changed the background color to black and rotated the sun lamp to a very steep angle. I also increased the size of the sun to 1, to get the smooth shadows

[image]

Comment: When i try to do this, my text doesnt get the black plane as a background. Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Cloth Physics, this video may help u

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjY2YXXIel8

If you want to get more control you can use sculpt mode to create the wrinkles.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOtOH5l9C-E

This video is a good reference.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.